# Short story from about 15 years ago: guy stumbles onto bunker of alien lizard people

Tags: story-identification

The book was about a guy who stumbles onto a bunker of lizard people aliens after strange things were happening.  I don't really remember much else.

I read the book about 15 years ago. I believe it was fairly new at the time. All I remember is that it was following a boy who was investigating strange things happening and stumbled on to a bunker underground. I believe the alien lizard people in the bunker were doing experiments on humans and animals.

I think he found a cow that was mutilated. There were lots of weird lights and sounds in the area. It was a short story.

Comment: Lizard people in a bunker is the scenario of the 1970s Doctor Who series "Doctor Who and the Silurians".  This was first broadcast in seven half hour episodes in 1970 and later novelised as "Doctor Who and the Cave Monsters".  In this story the Silurians are a race of reptile men from the time of the dinosaurs who place themselves in suspended animation in underground bunkers in order to survive an event when the moon is expected to temporarily remove the earth's atmosphere.  Not what you're looking for though - not a short story, older than 15 years.